# KVM / Extender needed... with no lag

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

I need to extend a PS/2 and Mouse, KB and VGA 220 feet (cat5 in place) to an audio editing console that is in a remote rack in a closet.

Audio from the unit is alredy extended. So thats not a problem.

My currect KVM system (avocent) has just enough lag to make audio editing painfull.

So the requrements are.

- must be over CAT5 (not IP)
- little or no lag (its used for audio editing so needs to be real time / instant repsonce)
- Ps/2 support (USB not needed) and VGA support

Any suggestions?

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one of these [Belkin KVM extenders](http://catalog.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=87618). It runs fine over CAT5 (not IP), I've never experienced any lag on it (however I don't have it on a long run of CAT5). It has both PS/2 and VGA.

There is a adjustment screw on the side that lets you tune the display (i.e. remove the shadow effect).

I'd certainly recommend it, however bear in mind that I never seen any other similar devices in use to be able to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

We've always used Raritan KVMs and we have a couple of their Cat5 extenders:

[Cat5 Reach](http://www.raritan.com/products/accessories-and-rack-management/cat5-reach/)

I've never noticed any lag in anything I've done, but then I've never tested it w/ audio since I'm using it to get to our KVM in the server room from my office.

It's not cheap, though, it looks like it's $300 for each end.